# Mongodb + Kerberos BadValue SASL mechanism GSSAPI is not supported

Tags: redhat, kerberos, mongodb, sasl, gssapi

I am trying to run an instance of mongodb with the authentication mechanism GSS-API. This is the command:

```
mongod --dbpath /home/ec2-user/db/node2/data --auth --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=GSSAPI
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
  F CONTROL  Failed global initialization: BadValue SASL mechanism GSSAPI is not supported
```

It seems that I need the library that SASL uses for the GSS-API mechanism, just like this other problem that I solved:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/mongodb-couldnt-find-mech-gssapi

But with the difference that now I am using a Linux Red Hat 7.5  and, before, I was using a Ubuntu 14.04. The libraries that I installed to try to solve this error are these:

```
cyrus-sasl-gssapi.i686 : GSSAPI authentication support for Cyrus SASL
cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64 : GSSAPI authentication support for Cyrus SASL
perl-GSSAPI.x86_64 : Perl extension providing access to the GSSAPIv2 library
rsyslog-gssapi.x86_64 : GSSAPI authentication and encryption support for rsyslog
gssproxy.x86_64 : GSSAPI Proxy
python-kerberos.x86_64 : A high-level wrapper for Kerberos (GSSAPI) operations
sssd-krb5-common.x86_64 : SSSD helpers needed for Kerberos and GSSAPI authentication
sssd-krb5-common.i686 : SSSD helpers needed for Kerberos and GSSAPI authentication
```

Does anyone know what library I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

In their document:

> MongoDB **Enterprise** supports authentication using a Kerberos
>   service.

Apparently their normal version doesn't support GSSAPI authentication mechanism,
so downloading the enterprise version should solve the problem.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-windows-with-kerberos-authentication/

Comment: I was using the enterprise version